# PostgreSQL : How to prevent SQL stored procedure from concurrent access ? (Including SELECT FOR UPDATE)

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, locking, database-performance

I have a trouble with a stored procedure which performs some load balancing algorithm. The service calls this procedure remotely and the procedure has to answer with the good port to forward the message.

The problem is that I want a great performance (500 caps or messages/s). So, the service is asking 500 times per second the database which is the good port to forward the message to it.

N.B. : I am sure that the VM in which I run the database server had enough ressources to reach 500 requests/s. As a matter of fact, I reach this number for more simple queries (Select, update ...).

Here is the stored procedure :

```
 -- Function: loadbalancing(integer)

 -- DROP FUNCTION loadbalancing(integer);

 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION loadbalancing(num integer)   RETURNS
 integer AS $BODY$DECLARE
 -- Declarations 
 port_selected integer; 
 total_call_attempts integer;

 BEGIN
 --
 -- ***   ***   ***   ***   ***   ***
 -- *** Load Balancing Algorithm  ***
 -- ***   ***   ***   ***   ***   ***
 --
 -- ***************
 -- *** locking ***
 -- ***************
 perform number_of_call_attempt, destination_rate FROM load_distribution WHERE loadb_id = num FOR UPDATE;

 -- *****************************
 -- *** select the right port ***
 -- ***************************** 
select port_number into port_selected from  ( select *, row_number()          over(order by destination_ratio asc,
 destination_target_rate desc, port_number asc) as rn from
 load_distribution where active = true and loadb_id = num ) t where
 t.rn = 1;

 -- ******************************************************
 -- *** Update the number of call attempts at one port ***
 -- ****************************************************** 
 UPDATE load_distribution SET number_of_call_attempt = number_of_call_attempt
 + 1 WHERE port_number = port_selected AND loadb_id = num;

 -- **************************************
 -- *** Get the total of call attempts ***
 -- **************************************
 SELECT SUM(number_of_call_attempt) into total_call_attempts FROM
 load_distribution WHERE loadb_id = num;

 -- *******************************
 -- *** Update destination rate ***
 -- ******************************* 
UPDATE load_distribution SET destination_rate = (number_of_call_attempt / total_call_attempts)
 WHERE loadb_id = num;

 -- ********************************
 -- *** Update destination ratio ***
 -- ******************************** 
 UPDATE load_distribution SET destination_ratio = (destination_rate / destination_target_rate) WHERE
 loadb_id = num;

 -- ***********************************************
 -- *** Return a port to the requesting service ***
 -- *********************************************** 
RETURN port_selected;

 END;$BODY$   LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE   COST 100; 
 ALTER FUNCTION loadbalancing(integer)   OWNER TO postgres;
```

The trouble I have is that this works for maximum 70 or 100 requests / second. When I start to reach 200 or more requests / second, the Postgres database sends a Timeout exception.

For what reason do you think this problem happens? As for me, I think that it is a problem of concurrent access. Indeed, the procedure is selecting a port number in function of other columns values. Those columns values are changed every time a call/request arrives. The request that comes right after have to use the changed values (clean state) and not values in a dirty state or unchanged values (If the next request comes while or before the value is changed by the previous request).

So, one solution I thought about is to make explicit locking with SELECT FOR UPDATE. Unfortunately, the one I put in my algorithm doesn't seem to work, or it is not the good solution. I am new with locking and stored procedures.

So, what do you think the solution can be to solve this issue? (i.e. to enhance performance to way more requests/s).

Comment: Commit strategy should be part of your question. Once you UPDATE a row, it's write-locked for everyone else until the transaction commits. So your *commit rate* is essential to determine the max. throughput of concurrent requests. Commit as early as possible and see if [asynchronous commit](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/wal-async-commit.html) can help.

Answer (score 0):

This strikes me as an exceedingly poor thing to try to do in the RDBMS. I'd use volatile storage, probably non-transactional. The best thing to do here is almost certainly to use an *existing, well established load balancing tool*, or if you must DIY, doing so using technologies designed for very low latency fast queries for small atomic pieces of data.

Doing multiple windowing and aggregation passes, in multiple queries, in a pl/pgsql stored procedure is about the worst way you could do this. Especially since you're basically serializing access on the rows.

You probably don't need this allocation to be precise, error-free and to perfectly respect the ratios allocated. Instead, you likely need it to be really fast, and roughly good enough. PL/PgSQL isn't the right tool for this job, to the point where there's barely any point advising you to improve it. It's just not going to work.

In addition to the locking issues, you're generating *massive* MVCC bloat with this fast-churn update process, which in turn generates more load doing vacuum cleanup. All for ACID guarantees you neither need nor want.

If you really must use this approach, a few things will help:

- `SET synchronous_commit = off` for the transactions calling the proc
- Use `UNLOGGED` tables for the port mapping tables
- Set `destination_ratio`, `destination_rate` and `number_of_call_attempt` in *one* `UPDATE` statement
- Use `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` to grab the desired port in your sort, not `row_number()`

... but really, the whole approach is doomed. It's hammering storage, doing writes for row locking and writes for `UPDATE`s, and it's doing aggregation passes every time. Even though it's probably all in `shared_buffers` there's massive churn involved. Using `UNLOGGED` tables with a `FILLFACTOR` somewhere around 30 might help, combined with async commit. A bit. It'll still just be slow.

Don't reinvent this wheel. Use an existing, well established load balancing system. You need something that can keep the statistics in memory, lazily updated, and that uses tricks like read-copy-update, CPU atomics, etc, to allow very high concurrency access to shared data structures. Something that doesn't try to be crash-safe or durable, and doesn't attempt to allocate perfectly fairly.